# What's wrong with this simple MYSQL bash script?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I want to run a single MYSQL command on the CLI, i made a bash file like this:

```
#! /bin/bash 

mysql --user=uuu --password=ppp DATABASE "UPDATE tickets SET status = 'open' WHERE ID = $1;"
```

When i do something like:

```
gabriel$ sh open.sh 123456
```

I get the full command help description and the script does nothing. I tried the query directly on the DB and works. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the -e flag.

```
mysql --user=uuu --password=ppp DATABASE -e "UPDATE tickets SET status = 'open' WHERE ID = $1;"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
mysql --user=uuu --password=ppp DATABASE < "UPDATE tickets SET status = 'open' WHERE ID = $1;"
```